# Azure Service bus queue - What if receiving Web API could not process the message

Tags: azure-servicebus-queues

As a part of data integration between two application, we plan to send data to Azure service bus queue. On the receiving end I've an API that loads the data to target DB.
 I need to understand how can I handle the following:
1. How should the API be notified whenever the messages arrives in the queue. I am thinking of Azure function or web job or some scheduling component. 
2. What if an API is down, messages should retain in queue. 
3. What if when API receives the message but somehow the target DB is down. In that case, my messages should be retained in the queue for retries.

Please help me and guide me to get the correct approach to implement this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Logic Apps! Use Logic Apps with Service Bus Queue Trigger so that it fires on the arrival of new messages in Service Bus Queue. To send the data to Web API, use Logic Apps Http Connector.

It is scalable by individual messages.

1. How should the API be notified whenever the messages arrives in the queue. I am thinking of Azure function or web job or some scheduling component. **Logic Apps**
2. What if an API is down, messages should retain in queue. **Azure Service Bus Queue ensures FIFO, Batching,.. Messages are retained until it is de-queued and deleted**
3. What if when API receives the message but somehow the target DB is down. In that case, my messages should be retained in the queue for retries. **Check transaction feature of Azure Service Bus Queue**

Comment: Thanks Ashokan.<br/>I checked for pt 3. transaction feature.. I guess that only works for sending the data to queue but not on receiving side...<br/> I ve few things which might work hence you can provide your suggestion <br/> 1. Once the message (PeekLock) is received by API and on successful processing of the message, I shall have the API to complete the message status in queue.

Comment: Yes, PeekLock() + DeleteOrMarkAsComplete() on successful completion will work. Are you planning to use Logic Apps?

Comment: Not sure if Logic app is right, because if in case my API is down then though the message would retain in queue but it would never process as the Logic app would be on trigger of new message.. . I am thinking of web job and schedule it run every couple of minutes so in that case if API is down it would retain the message and next schedule run would process the previous batch too (if API is up)..  . what do you think?

Comment: I vote for ReceiveAndDelete() for service bus queue message using Logic Apps or other jobs (which is your choice). If message is processed, then it is fine. Otherwise, re-queue the message to service bus message if message processing order is not a concern. I am recommending Logic Apps as it is designer-based & ready-to-plug; no different from Web Jobs or Console Apps.

Comment: Thanks Ashokan for your feedback.. . but message processing order is needed and should be FIFO..

Comment: Oh! Then, parallelism is not possible for your case; it should be single-threaded and it can always process one message at a time.